# What capabilities would a cat that lived a million years have?

Tags: fauna

Our cats learn to vaguely express desires vocally (with different style meows for *'I want to eat'* and *'I'm scared'*, for example) and can do some simple tasks that suggest they are capable of slowly figuring out the world around them, such as knocking on the door knob when they want out of a room.

If one cat was chosen to live for a million years, after the million years were finished, is it possible that the cat would have learned enough to function at a higher level than cats do now?

E.g. would it be able to converse to some degree with humans?  Open its own food?  Other things?

Comment: Why open your own food if you can command a human to do it for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is no, cats have a limited brain capacity and internal connectivity/complexity.

An adult cat will learn some new skills still, but over time old skills will fade away so there is a finite limit to just how much can be learnt and there are some things (such as human speach) that they don't have the physical or mental capacity to ever learn.

Comment: I am a cat and I am offended by that.

Comment: Oh, long Johnson.

Comment: @Namechangedtomaskidentity - Don't worry, you won't remember it for long.